# Is there a way to do determine if an object is an "instance" of a pep484 style expression at runtime?

Tags: python

I've often found myself writing multi-statement expressions to validate the types of variables at runtime. For example, supposing I wanted to verify that a particular input is a list of Foo objects, I might have to write the following expression:

```
assert(_isinstance(x, list) and all(_isinstance(y, Foo) for y in x))
```

I'd much rather be able to write something like:

```
# pseudocode
_assert(isinstance(x, typing.List[Foo]))
```

In other words, I want to ask x is a list of instances of Foo.

If this could be made to work, this would be better because the Pep484 syntax is a great way to concisely specify the types of nested structures. Of course, we all know that this isn't the way Python's built-in isinstance function works... but just dream with me for a moment:

We are all familiar with the isnstance function which returns True if the outer type of a structure is an instance of a class:

```
# real python:
isinstance(["a", "b", "c"], list) => True
```

But suppose I want to do deeper checks: I'd like to do something like:

```
# pseudocode:
import typing
_isinstance("x", str) => True
_isinstance(["a", "b", "c"], typing.List[str]) => True
_isinstance(["a", "b", "c"], typing.List[float]) => False
_isinstance([{"x":3}], typing.List[typing.Map[str,int]]) => True
```

So the idea is that the function would return True if the 1st argument fully corresponded to the Pep484 style expression of the 2nd argument.

Of course, some of you will point out that explicit static and runtime type checking goes against the spirit of "duck-typing". That's true - but not useful. Sometimes you really do want to validate the structure of an input. As projects get bigger you sometimes want the ability to know for sure what types you are dealing with and at other times you want the flexibility that duck-typing gives you.

So here's my question: Has anybody seen a way to compare Pep484 style expressions against types? If there already is a library or function to do it then I'd rather not re-invent the wheel. Perhaps the typing library already has a way to do this. Point me to it please!

Comment: You have used `isinstance` backwards in all your hypothetical examples. Not that it would have worked if you'd flipped it. `isinstance` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: It was backwards in one example - I've corrected that, thank you!

Comment: You just made it backwards in another example. The prototype is `isinstance(obj, type_or_tuple_of_types)`, not `isinstance(type_or_tuple_of_types, obj)`. Testing if `x` is of type or subtype of `list` is `isinstance(x, list)`, not `isinstance(list, x)`.

Comment: Now you seem to be asking for a tool, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Also, how can you find out whether _all_ of the dictionary's keys are strings and _all_ of the values are integers _without iterating over `dictionary.items()`_? In C++ you have strict typing, so it's _impossible_ to return something other than, for example, some kind of dictionary that maps strings to integers. This is not the case with Python.

Comment: If there's a way of doing it without a tool then that's what I want. For example it might be a feature of the typing library which is still pretty new.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I really want to correct this, could you point me to exactly which bit of pseudocode is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Since your "fix", literally every use of `isinstance` has its arguments reversed. Every single one. `isinstance(list, x)` should be `isinstance(x, list)`, `isinstance(Foo, y)` should be `isinstance(y, Foo)`, etc. The object being checked is the first argument, the type(s) it's being checked against are the second argument. Check [the `isinstance` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: Oops, thanks! I've corrected this. Thanks for your attention to detail - however I'd ike to reiterate, the point of the question is not "how do I use isinstance" but "how do I validate instances against pep484 expressions at runtime".

Answer (score -1):

You could've done it like this:

```
def _isinstance(var, type):
    if not isinstance(var, type):
        return False

    if isinstance(var, Iterable) and not isinstance(var, Generator):
        return all(any(isinstance(v, t) for t in type.__parameters__) for v in var)

    return True
```

Of course, this isn't that much different than what you've already got, but it gives the 'simplicity' of doing `assert(isinstance(x, List[Foo]))`. Here `x` must be iterable.

Note that one cannot determine the types of the data a generator will produce without iterating through it, thus losing all that data.

Python is *duck-typed* and doesn't care about types much. If something quacks like a duck, then it's a duck for Python.

Comment: Hi, saying that "Python is duck-typed and doesn't care about types much" is not particularly helpful. Sometimes you really have to validate types (e.g. at interface borders). At other times, we can relax a bit and trust duck typing. I agree that in the case of single-use traversable structures (e.g. Generators) you couldn't validate the input without rendering the object useful, but that's true however you want to validate your types!

Comment: @SalimFadhley, well, this is the truth... If you find yourself in need to check types in Python, you may be doing something the wrong way and may want to switch to some strong-typed language, although in C++, for example, checking the type explicitly (with an `if` clause, for example), is considered to be a bad practice, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you think this is an inappropriate question: Python 3.5.x specifies a mini-language explicitly for the purpose of specifying types (for type-hinting), my question is whether there is a way to use these same expressions to validate types at runtime. This is not something that every project will need, but something that will be quite handy in my case - It's an oldish project with quite a lot of structured data.